# Push Plugin register failed

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

I've install the phonegap-push-plugin for send push notification to android and iOS device.

No problem for android but when I try it on my iPhone, I can see some bug in the device console.

When I try to `init();` the result into device console was :

```
Push Plugin register failed
4.13.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM012002] Error in application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: aucune autorisation « aps-environment » valide détectée pour l’application
```

I do a lot of search but I didn't find anything was help me and is for that I ask it to the community now.

I build my application with Phonegap build cli 8.0.0
The plugin was : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push at the master branch

push plugin config.xml part's :

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm">
    <param name="SENDER_ID" value="123456789" />
</plugin>
```

I send notification with FCM and a correct push certificat and I think my web service who send notification work correctly cause he perfectly work for the android branch.

iPhone 5c (A1456) iOS 10.3.3.

Thanks for you'r futur help.

Comment: Switch the device to English so we can understand the exact error message thrown, and you can Google it as well. In French it won't help much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you have enabled the *Push Notifications* capability in the *General* section from Xcode.

Also re-check all the suggestions from this post:
[Firebase on Cordova doesn't trigger notifications on iOS Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53303132/161293)